# Sparse Checkout on Specific work directory

Tags: git, laravel, github, sparse-checkout

I am trying to accomplish the auto deploy of project to my shared hosting server.

What i am trying to accomplish is that the public directory needs to be checked out in the www directory, where as the other files and directories needs to checkout on the directory under root e-g `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files`

I see there is a "Sparse Checkout" option in git.

but i need to checkout to two different work directories with two different sets of files.

public will go to the `/home/{username}/public_html/`
where as remaining laravel project files will go under `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files`

I am just a GUI user of git, but hopefully there might be a solution or any other better way to handle this.

i am using github webhooks to auto deploy the project to my hosting server.

Comment: Wouldn't be the easiest to put everything in `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files` and then make a symlink at `/home/{username}/public_html/` that points to `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files/public`?

Comment: @Vampire i didnt thought of that. you are genius. 

But how to do symlinks through the ssh on cpanel??

Comment: 1.Initialize the two directories as git repositories. Do sparse-checkout twice. Or, 2. Copy specific files where they are needed.

Comment: What is different between normal SSH and SSH through cpanel?

Comment: @Vampire

I followed your way. and its working fine..

Actually i am trying this on shared hosting cpanel. a2hosting. they give access to git and ssh. so we can install laravel application easily and have access to composer commands as well.

Comment: @Vampire
As i followed your advice and did a symbolic link, but there is one issue here.

when new file has been created in that directory then that new file is not automatically shown to the target directory. i will have to make a symbolic link back again to make it work :(

rest seems ok.

here is how i made a symbolic link

`ln -s /path/to/{laravelProject}/public/* /home/{username}/public_html/`

working fine but when new file has been introduced in public directory then that file is not auto synced to the public_html directory.

Comment: @ElpieKay
Yes you are right. this can also be a way. but then i will have to make two webhooks, two repositories and will be doing two different git checkouts for a single project.

So if i have one more laravel project, i will have to have 4 repositories and so on. Works but dosen't seem right to me.
However symbolic link way seemed a better way by vampire but it also has a flaw that needs to be looked over.

Comment: @SizzlingCode whichever solution you take, I think all the jobs can be done by some scripts automatically.

Comment: You did **not** make one symbolic link how I advised. You made `n` symbolic links, `n` being the amount of files in `public`. With this (one symlink per file) you of course do not get new files in public_html. Instead you have to make the folder `public_html` a symlink to `public` like with `rm -rf /home/{username}/public_html/ && ln -s /path/to/{laravelProject}/public /home/{username}/public_html`.

Comment: @Vampire
Thanks for Solution, i will try this. Your Solution Helped in alot <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put everything in `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files` and then make a symlink at `/home/{username}/public_html/` that points to `/home/{username}/laravel-project-files/public` with something like `rm -rf /home/{username}/public_html/ && ln -s /path/to/{laravelProject}/public /home/{username}/public_html`.